# How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^d\int_{{\bf R}^d}|\nabla u_i(x)|^2\ dx=\int_{{\bf R}^d}|\nabla\times u|^2\ dx $ provided that $\nabla\cdot u=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

In the introduction chapter of the book [*Navier-Stokes Equations and Turbulence*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521064600), the following is stated with only a one-sentence proof:

> Suppose $u$ is a smooth velocity field on ${\bf R}^d$ ($d=2,3$) decaying sufficiently rapidly at infinity and it is divergence free: $\nabla\cdot u=0$. Then *integration by parts*  implies that
>   $$
> \sum_{i=1}^d\int_{{\bf R}^d}|\nabla u_i(x)|^2\ dx=\int_{{\bf R}^d}|\nabla\times u|^2\ dx.\tag{1}
> $$

None of the [versions of integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions) I know involves the curl operator.

Could anyone elaborate how (1) can be proved?

Comment: [The link has been broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jModF.png).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: Thanks for the report. I have changed the link to a new one. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. For $n=2$, you have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left|\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}\right|^2\ dxdy =&\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\partial_x u_2|^2+|\partial_y u_1|^2-2(\partial_x u_2 \partial_y u_1)\ dxdy\\
=&\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\partial_x u_2|^2+|\partial_y u_1|^2+(\partial_x\partial_y u_2) u_1+u_2(\partial_y\partial_x u_1)\ dxdy.
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot u = \partial_x u_1 + \partial_y u_2 = 0 \ \ \implies \ \ \ \partial_y u_2 = -\partial_x u_1
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\partial_x\partial_y u_2) u_1+u_2(\partial_y\partial_x u_1)\ dxdy =&\ -\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(\partial_x^2 u_1) u_1+u_2(\partial_y^2 u_2)\ dxdy\\
=&\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\partial_x u_1|^2+|\partial_y u_2|^2\ dxdy.
\end{align}
Hence it follows that
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left|\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y}\right|^2\ dxdy  = \sum^2_{i=1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\nabla u_i|^2\ dxdy.
\end{align}

For the $n=3$ case, we will need to use the following vector identities
\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{F}\times \operatorname{curl}\mathbf{G}) =&\  ( \operatorname{curl}\mathbf{F})\cdot(\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{G})-\mathbf{F}\cdot(\operatorname{curl}(\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{G}))\\
=&\  (\operatorname{curl} \mathbf{F})\cdot(\operatorname{curl}\mathbf{G})- \mathbf{F}\cdot (\nabla(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{G})-\nabla^2\mathbf{G})
\end{align}
where $\nabla^2$ is the vector Laplacian. Any how, set $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{G} = u$, then we have
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot (u\times \operatorname{curl} u) = |\operatorname{curl}u|^2+u\cdot \nabla^2 u
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\nabla\times u|^2\ d^3x =&\ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\nabla\cdot(u\times [\nabla \times u])-u\cdot \nabla^2u\ d^3x\\
=&\ \sum^3_{i=1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |\nabla u_i|^2\ d^3x.
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 u = [ \nabla^2 u_1, \nabla^2 u_2, \nabla^2 u_3].
\end{align}